# Python3.4 + SUDS - Can I disable SSL checking? "ssl.CertificateError" Issue

Tags: python, ssl, https, certificate, suds

I'm using python 3.4 and SUDS to access an API. It's a fairly simple process and I'm trying to run the following code:

```
from suds.client import Client

my_client = Client('URL HERE')

# rest of code ...
```

The problem is that the URL is a secure (HTTPS) url, using TLS 1.0 I believe, and running the code gives me the error:

```
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'HOSTNAME HERE' doesn't match 'CERTIFICATE HOSTNAME HERE'
```

as the URL is using the wrong certificate, although I know it is trustworthy. I've removed the actual host-names for the sake of privacy.

Is there any way to force SUDS to ignore the certificate mismatch (similarly to how one can manually proceed to such a site in a browser) and run with the URL anyway?